# Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::exists does not exist

Tags: laravel

I have two fields `product_id` and `user_id`. Hide the registration button when the user registers a product. It means to register once.

```
@if(auth()->user()->orders->where('user_id', $product->id)->exists())
    @if(App\Services\Cart\Cart::count($product) < $product->inventory)
        <form action="{{ route('add.to.cart', $product->id) }}" method="post" id="add-to-cart">
            @csrf
        </form>
        <span onclick="document.getElementById('add-to-cart').submit()" class="cursor-pointer btn btn-lg bg-navy-blue text-white">
            <span>Order</span>
        </span>
    @endif
@endif
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are using eloquent relationship. So auth()->user()->orders will return a collection, and collection doesn't have exists method. Use auth()->user()->orders() to return a query builder instead.

And I guess column of where condition is product_id. So try:

```
auth()->user()->orders()->where('product_id', $product->id)->exists()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But the button did not display.

Comment: Check to see if the product exists in orders of user?

Comment: When I want to register another product, I see that there is no registration button.

Comment: You put the button in if statement. It is just shown when the condition matches

Comment: So why doesn't it show?